# QRCode electronics

Tags: camera, detection

I am designing a portable device meant to be connected to multiple computers and able to recognize them. I am thinking of a qrcode, different for every computer and displayed on their screen, that my device can detect.
What do I need for such an application? can a cheap camera (less than VGA) do the job? Do you know any IC that can do the job without writing a proper algorithm on my MCU (XMEGA).

Comment: Depending on your exact application a simpler method might be to flicker the screen in a certain pattern and recognize it with photo diodes. The german chiptan system for online banking uses such an approach with five flickering fields.

Comment: @starblue You should turn this comment into an answer so people can vote on it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your exact application a simpler method might be to flicker the screen in a certain pattern and recognize it with one or more photo diodes.

For example, the german "chipTAN comfort" TAN generator for online banking uses such an approach. There are five flickering fields on the bank's web page which transfer data to the TAN generator.

The data includes the account number and the amount, which both are displayed and used in the computation of the TAN, so checking this data is a very effective countermeasure against phishing.

Unfortunately I didn't find any web page in English describing the system, so here is one in german: http://6xq.net/html/00/20.html

Comment: +1 interesting device. Wikipedia has a pretty [photo of chipTAN comfort (flickering)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaktionsnummer#chipTAN_comfort.2Fsm.40rtTAN_optic_.28Flickering.29).

Comment: The Timex Datalink also read data off a flickering computer screen.[1](http://www.bobdbob.com/~protius/timex/) [2](http://www.ferretronix.com/~protius/timex/) Perhaps that would be an easier protocol to implement.

Comment: My initial thought was along similar lines. The question doesn't describe project goals or constraints well in terms of cost/complexity and what hardware is available. On the cheater end you can use an Android phone and QR reader app... If the point is to DIY, something like a photodiode amp and blinky patterns would probably be fun and realistic. I'll bet there are MCU/RFID tag reader combos that would be much simpler as well. QR brings a lot of complexity along with a camera, image processing software required, OS to run it, etc. QRs carry like 3KB of data, you don't need anywhere near that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to connect them to the computers (as you wrote) then maybe a software-based detection method would be easier?

If you use Ethernet (no very expensive anymore) you can get the MAC address which is globally unique (a USB solution would require some drivers since there are no unique computer identifiers used in the enumeration).

Comment: I'm actually using Bluetooth. The issue here is that the device can be connected to 2 computers but I need to know which one I'm interacting with. So the idea I got is to show on the screen some qrcode and recognise it with my device, equipped with some qrcode detector.

Comment: Maybe you could use the software you got on the PC to somehow notify the Bluetooth device (virtual com port over Bluetooth is quite easy IIRC)? It seems simpler to me than any machine vision approach.

Comment: It's the bluetooth device, that you keep in your hand like a pen, that decides which computer to use, not the other way round. I though vision or color coding were the only possibilities

Comment: So you basically want a contact less but short range mean of pairing the device with one computer or another? So when the user is in proximity of a computer he will be able to use your pen with it without touching any keys or doing any switching?

Comment: exactly! and I was thinking about something displayed by the computer that my device can recognize..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rfid would be easier computation wise than QR codes. QR is a fairly complicated algorithm even with known pixels. Throw in the required image processing and it is pretty heavy duty stuff. RFID readers and cards are cheap and reliable.